# git: get effective GIT_DIR, if current dir is a working tree subdir and $GIT_DIR is unset

Tags: git

From a script, how to determine the current GIT_DIR?
If not overriden, it's just the top level dir or the top level dir of a bare repo.

I want something like:

```
[/git/repo1/subdir]$ git show-git-dir
/git/repo1/.git
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done with [rev-parse](http://jk.gs/git-rev-parse.html):

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

Comment: FWIW, `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` may also be useful to some (it's what I actually wanted) -- this would give the base working tree (i.e. where the `.git` directory is, usually, though not in the case of a `git worktree` scenario), rather than the `.git` directory path itself.  (Sometimes one wants one, sometimes one wants the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure bash version, and will find the directory when you are in the root.
(Ikke's solution is better by the way).

```
a=$PWD

while [ "$a" != "" ] && [ "$a" != '/' ];
do
    a=`dirname $a`;
    if [ -d $a/.git ];
    then
        echo "$a";
        break;
    fi
done
```

On windows you will probably have to add another [ "$a" != '\' ] to test for that case, and I dont have access at the moment to check if the bash shell that comes with Msysgit supports "dirname".

But works in Terminator on Ubuntu.